# Set value to Vue model from rails rendering process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, erb

I create a complete rails application but I add the `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>` a.k.a. Vue framework just for handling a few and specific tasks. One of those tasks is to controll a range input component like this:

**_a_single_layout.html.erb**

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>{{progress}}%</h1>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" v-model="progress">
</div>
```

**application.js**

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    progress: 0
  }
})
```

**What I get:**

[image]

The problem is how to set the current stored value from the rails application here and at the same time, bind this value to the Vue model.

**What I have tried:**

```
<h1>{{progress = <%= @model.progress %>}}%</h1>
```

● This actually asigns the value just as I want but the range input get stuck.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" v-bind:progress="<%= @model.progress %>">
```

● This moves the range to its expected position but stops refreshing the view when I move it with the mouse.

```
<input type="range" v-model="progress" v-bind:progress="<%= @model.progress %>">
```

● Set both, `v-model` and `v-bind` makes the last one be ignored.

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    progress: <%= @model.progress %>
  }
})
```

● Also I have tried to write the value in the javascript side, but this is not a valid syntax for rails.

● I have looking for something like `v-on:load="progress = <%= @model.progress %>"` but doesn't seems v-on has any load event handler.

Here are the things I have tried on a pen: https://codepen.io/alex3o0/pen/XWrLwwm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just go with a kind of tricky solution; I set my rails model variable to a Vue model variable wich get "stuck" but on the created method (using a setTimeout to delay the action ¯\_(ツ)_/¯) I reasign this value to a second and totaly free Vue model variable:

**_a_single_layout.html.erb**

```
<div id="app">
  <span class="hide-me">{{real_value = <%= @model.progress %>}}</span><!-- this variable gets the value from the rails model but also gets "stuck" -->
  <h1>{{progress}}%</h1>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" v-model="progress"><!-- this variable will get its real value when the "created" method starts -->
</div>
```

**application.js**

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    progress: 0,
    real_value: 0
  },
  created: function(){
    setTimeout(() => this.progress = this.real_value, 1000)
  }
})
```

By the way, I am still looking for a "correct" solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a Vue component.
Then you can pass your 'rails' data to Vue through this component with props. You just need to convert it to JSON first:

**_a_single_layout.html.erb**

```html
<div id="app">
  <load-progress :progress="<%= @model.progress.to_json %>"></load-progress>
</div>
```

**application.js**

```
const LoadProgress = Vue.component('load-progress', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>{{ progress }}%</p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" :value="progress">
    </div>`,
  props: ['progress']
})

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: { LoadProgress }
})
```